# $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire() did not refresh the record detail component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, event, refresh

I have created a lightning component for the lightning experience record pages. In the customize record page, I drag standard Record Detail component and my component to the page. In my component, I update some fields of a record. After I save those field, I fire up the `e.force:refreshView` event. But the standard record detail component did not refresh to show the new value of those field. Is there any way to force to refresh the standard record detail component?

Here's the code:-

**Component:**

```
<div>
<force:recordView recordId="{!v.recordId}"/>
</div>
<div>...some input field... <ui:button label="Save" press="{!c.save}"/> 
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
save : function(component) {
    var action = component.get("c.saveInput");
    action.setParams({
        "objectName" : component.get("v.sObjectName"),
        "recordId" : component.get("v.recordId"),
        "postcode": component.get("v.postcode"),
        "city": component.get("v.city"),
        "state": component.get("v.state"),
        "country": component.get("v.country"),
        "street": component.get("v.street")
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(action) {
        $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
 }
```

Comment: Can you share the code snippet? I tried at my end, it did refresh the record detail component with new values

Comment: UI:
 <div><force:recordView recordId="{!v.recordId}"/></div>
<div>...some input field...
<ui:button label="Save" press="{!c.save}"/> </div>
Controller 
 save : function() {
        var action = component.get("c.save");
        action.setCallback(this, function(action) {
            $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
     }
    After the callback, the record view did not refresh. The doc says this event will only be handled in the one.app container. I am not sure if my case will trigger the handler in the one.app container?

Comment: are you telling the `<force:recordView/>` did not refresh with new values, when `$A.get('e.force:refreshView')` is fired?

Comment: I assume I just need to fire the event and there is a predefined handler to automatically refresh the record view. I did not do anything to stop refreshing.

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to give same name to the apex controller's method and the function which is called on click.
 Also, you should pass event along with the component in the same.
Please find the code below:-

**Controller:-**

```
save : function(component, event) {                
        var action = component.get("c.apexSave"); 
        action.setCallback(this, function(action) {                
           $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire(); 
        }); 
        $A.enqueueAction(action); 
    }
```

Note **save** and **apexSave**.

*The server-side action is also provided by the “c” value provider. This is the same value provider that provides the JavaScript controller event handler which handles the press event of the button and the init event. Because of this, you need to make sure that **you do not name your Apex controller methods with the same name as your JavaScript controller methods**. It’s easy to make the mistake of naming them same because it is natural to want to be consistent in naming.*

Source:- [Salesforce1 Lightning Components – Working with Controllers](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/03/lightning-components.html)

You may use an aura handler to make sure that whether it has been refreshed successfully.

```
<aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.isRefreshed}" />
```

Comment: Yes. I did not use the same name in my original code. The input values are saved to the database, but just the refreshing did not work.

Comment: My dear @YingLuan Then, kindly please post your "original code" instead of posting your "duplicate code"! It saves lots of time.
Can you pls tell me how you're making sure that it's not being refreshed?

Comment: Also @YingLuan it did work at my end with the above code. As I've edited the answer you may use an aura handler to make sure that whether it has been refreshed successfully.
    <aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.isRefreshed}" />

Comment: I'm very sorry for the misleading codes and thanks a lot for your help. Just because that it has the characters limitations, so I deleted some codes at the beginning. I already updated the question with my codes. So the save operation will modify the address of the record and then fire the refresh event, but I did not see the new address showing. I tried the "isRefreshed" handler and add an alert there, I can see the alert showing but not the new address.

Comment: And If I want to remove <force:recordView recordId="{!v.recordId}"/> from my component and drag the standard record detail view in the lightning experience record pages with my component as well. In the save function, if I fire the force:refreshView event, will it refresh the standard record detail component?

Comment: @YingLuan Please share your Apex Controller code (Mainly, the part where you've written code to update the data).

And yes, all the components present in that page will be refreshed.

Comment: @SE_User: Your comments are just rude and drive away people from SFSE. Once in a while every member of this forum makes a mistake when reducing the problematic code to a size that fits inside a SFSE question. 

I flagged you as I think we shouldn't accept this kind of harch tone here.

Comment: @RobertSösemann You may please go through the previous comments and the edits of the question as well as the comment by the OP in the other answer here. Its ok to correct one, two or even 3 times. There won't be any problem if he had posted his "original code" here. And for your very kind information, I was sincerely trying to help him out in the first place.

Comment: @SE_User: and then you just freaked out ;-)

Comment: @RobertSösemann Hope you had look into the previous edits as well as the comment to other answer. Even you would've done the same thing (or just go away without replying). But I hold onto the same and still tried to help which I strongly believe was a positive gesture from my part. I guess the OP has understood his mistake and even corrected it and I continued to help him even after all this. So I do not think this would drive people away from such an awesome forum with so many people who are out there to help each other.

Answer (score 0):

You have'nt given **component** as a parameter in functions defined in the controller. But you are accessing component in your code.

Modify your code as follows.

```
save : function(component) { 
  var action = component.get("c.save"); 
  action.setCallback(this, function(action) {
    $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire(); 
  }); 
  $A.enqueueAction(action); 
}
```

Comment: I do have component as a parameter in my code, just like what you provide. But the refreshing still does not work.