# Do Lightning Components need to register/declare standard app events?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, event

My Lightning component:

```
<aura:component controller="MyController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id"/>
    ...
    <button type="button" onclick="{!c.doRun}">Activate Next</button>
</aura:component>
```

which is embedded into a **Standard Layout** using **Visualforce** and **Lightning Out**

```
<apex:page standardController="CustomObject__c">
    <apex:includeLightning />

    <div id="mydiv" />

    <script>
    $Lightning.use("myApp", function() {
        $Lightning.createComponent("myComponent",
                                   { recordId : "{!CustomObject__c.Id}" },
                                   "mydiv",
                                   function(cmp) {});
    });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

is unable to fire the standard app event `$A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire()`

```
({doRun : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.run");

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        if (component.isValid() && response.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
            $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);        
}})
```

When I click the button this error appears on the screen:

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Error in
>   $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'fire' of undefined] Failing
>   descriptor:

DISCLAIMER: I know that this is a duplicate of [$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire() did not refresh the record detail component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/134223) but this question got lost in irrelevant details and found no solution yet.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour is documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out_considerations.htm).For lightning out if you are outside the SF1 container or lightning experience ,then standard events will not work .

Update:

I understand that you are inside the lightning experience and in that case try registering the event

```
<aura:registerEvent name="refreshView" type="force:refreshView" />
```

Comment: But the user has Lightning active and is looking at a Lightning version of a records detail page (defined by a standard layout with an embedded VF page).  How can I reload the current page instead?

Comment: Ah I see .Ok let me update my answer .

Comment: I had to use <aura:registerEvent name="refreshView" type="force:refreshView" /> and it indeed worked. But only the embedded page reloads not the whole visualforce page.

Comment: So only detail page reloaded and not the VF page ? You can use callback and call a non-lightning code (wndow.reload()) using https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_external.htm

Comment: When I do this i get a cross site error: Error in $A.getCallback() [Blocked a frame with origin "https://myns.na8.visual.force.com" from accessing a cross-origin

Comment: @RobertSösemann try using `window.parent.location.href="/"+recordId` instead of `window.reload()`

Comment: @RobertSösemann above would work for classic view but for lightning experience you need this : `window.parent.location.href= '/one/one.app#/sObject/'+recordId+'/view'`

Comment: @Praveen When I do this it always "restarts Lightning" meaning I always see the Winter'17 logo. Isn't there a way to reload with this?

Comment: @RobertSösemann, since the reload needs to happen from the vf page, above method is the only way to do it as far as I know.